# how to deal duplicated chars in common strings when applying Jaro String Similarity algorithm

Tags: r, string, algorithm, jaro-winkler, stringdist

I am struggling the definition of common string between two strings when applying Jaro string similarity algorithm.

say we have

```
 s1 = 'profjohndoe'
 s2 = 'drjohndoe'
```

BY Jaro similarity, the half length is `floor(11/2) - 1 = 4`, defined by the algorithm, `s1[i] = s2[j]` is counted to be common, if `abs(i-j)<=4`

then mapping matrix is

```
  p r o f j o h n d o e
d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
r 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
j 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
o 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
h 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
o 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
e 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

therefore:

```
char_ins1_canfound_ins2 would be 'rojohndoe' (in their presented order in s1);
char_ins2_canfound_ins1 would be 'rjohndoe' (in their presented order in s2).
```

Now I am having a case that common char strings have non equal lengths, how to deal with that?

if applying 'stringdist' function in R 'stringdist' pack, will obtain the following result:

```
> 1 - stringdist('profjohndoe','drjohndoe',method='jw')
[1] 0.7887205
```

which appear to be:

> 1/3*(8/9+8/11+(8-2)/8)
>       [1] 0.7887205

above outcome indicates stringdist counted common string with length 8. Following this fact,
   if I massage `char_ins1_canfound_ins2` to be 'rojohnde', there should be 6 transpositions, which should yield to 1/3*(8/9+8/11+(8-3)/8)
   if I massage `char_ins1_canfound_ins2` to be 'rojhndoe', there should be 2 transpositions, which should yield to 1/3*(8/9+8/11+(8-1)/8)

How is R `stringdist` function deals with above situation?

Millions of thanks!